# Nesting generation in built_value

Tags: dart-pub, built-value

I have next project structure:

```
app/pubspec.yaml
packages/app_part/pubspec.yaml
```

**Both projects** are using built_value immutable models.

*app/pubspec.yaml:*

```
name: app
dependencies:
  built_value: ^6.7.1
  app_part:
    path: ../packages/app_part
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.6.7
  built_value_generator: ^6.7.1
```

*packages/app_part/pubspec.yaml:*

```
name: app_part
dependencies:
  built_value: ^6.7.1
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.6.7
  built_value_generator: ^6.7.1
```

I'm executing `pub run build_runner watch` inside `app` folder of the project.

`built_value_generator` generates `.g.dart` only for sources which are located in `app`, not in `packages/app_part`

**So, how to run `build_runner watch` to generate code for all `app` dependencies)?** 
(at least local dependencies, specified with `path`)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it is impossible to run in directly from the `build_runner`.

I made helper script for this case:

https://gist.github.com/Hacker-CB/c699b618ca72ca968e70b471bf4d0d0a